# React Native generating a "react is undefined" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs

so I'm building a simple application with react-native, just to test it out, and i have problems with builind it/making it work

In my App i have just the imports for react-native and a simple button, the problem I'm pretty sure it is in the webpack.config file.

Here is the code of it:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  externals: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!react-native)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: [ "@babel/preset-env", 
                              ["@babel/preset-react",  {"runtime": "automatic"}]
                            ] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
    port: 9000,
  },
  resolve: { extensions: [".*", ".js", ".jsx"],
},
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "",
    chunkFilename: '[id].js',
    filename: "hello_world.js"
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
  { 
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
    filename: "hello_world.html",
    inject: "body"
   }),
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
   }),
],
   performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
},
}
```

If i build this, i get the error:

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /opt/my-folder/workspace/my-folder2/portal/_reactPlugins/helloWorld/node_modules/react-native/index.js: Unexpected keyword 'typeof'. (14:7)

Looking a bit around forums, the only thing that ***almost worked for me was adding

```
externals:{
   "react-native": true
}
```

in this way the program successfully builds, but when i go to test it i get and error "react is undefined" relative to that line.

Any clue on how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks